# How to change size of only one element in a class while keeping everything else the same?

Tags: html, css

I want to change the width of one of my elements in my "logos" class using Javascript. But when I change the width of the target element in my "logos" class to 5.9%, the positioning of the other elements also changed. I want the positioning the other elements to not change when I increase the size of the image inside their shared div. Is there any way to get around this? I'm pretty new to css, thanks for your help.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css"> 
<title>Sexism in Silicon Valley</title>
</head>
<body id="body">
<div class="parentz"id="parent1">
    <img src="img1.png" class="logos" id="id1">
    <img src="img2.png" class="logos" id="id2">
    <img src="img3.png" class="logos" id="id3">
    <img id="id4" src="img4.png" class="logos">
</div>
<div class="parentz" id="parent2">
    <img src="img5.png" class="logos" id="id5">
    <img src="img6.png" class="logos" id="id6">
    <img src="img7.png" class="logos" id="id7">
    <img src="img8.png" class="logos" id="id8">
</div>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
body { 
    background: #907D7C; 
    -webkit-transition: background 1.5s;

} 
.parentz {
    background: #907D7C;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 9%;
    border: white;
    border: 5px;


    -webkit-transition: background 1.5s;

}

#parent2 {
    margin-top: 3%;

}

.logos {
    width: 5.5%;
    height: 18%;
    border-radius: 90px;  
    margin-right: 25px; 
    padding: .5%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another class like 'logoslarge' and use that to override size so you will have 'logos logoslarge' as class on that element.You can then just write

> .logoslarge { width:5.9%}

This would only apply to those elements that have new class.

Comment: I want to be able to change every element's width without affecting the rest of it.. so i would have to make a separate class for each element?

Comment: if each width is different you can but for common width just create one class and apply to all elements that need same width. For example class for 5.8 with can be applied to 3 elements. Try it.

Comment: This is probably the best approach, however if you aren't interested in the functionality being responsive, i'd just specify the width style inline. This would override the external css style. <img src="img8.png" class="logos" id="id8" style="width:5.9%;">

Comment: I think you misunderstand the problem. In Javascript i'm doing essentially the same thing, i'm targeting only one of the elements.
But this still affects the position of the other elements